# A call to console.error('String') is diagnosed as an error (with a red X in the source), while console.log('String') works fine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome Developer Tools 121.0.6167.161 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Javascript code calling console.error('String') fails with an error at run-time, marking the call with a red X in the source, and the string is not printed on the console. Changing console.error to console.log produces no error and the string gets printed on the console. Here is a screenshot showing the source marked with the error (there was no mark when the debugger paused at the breakpoint on the previous line), and the console showing other console.log output, but not the string passed to console.error.

I also note that the top line shows a red X followed by '1', which normally indicates that 1 error was detected, and clicking the X will take you to the error in the source. But in this case, clicking that X has no effect (similarly for the X in the source listing and the underlined source). I can't get Devtools to tell me what it thinks is wrong with the call to console.error()!

[image: Devtools window]

*** EDIT ***
I should also note that uncommenting the call to console.assert() on line 680 gives the same treatment to that call as well: the call is treated as a run-time error, with no explanation. I guess it would sort of make sense if the console object were inaccessible, but console.log() works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Switch `Custom levels` in console toolbar to `Default`? Also see if you have enabled "Selected context only" in the console options.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't see anything that says "Custom levels" in the DevTools toolbar, and can't find it when clicking the >> at the end end of it... Oh wait, I see, down lower there's a menu bar for just the console, and it has a select box where I can select "Default" - better yet, "Verbose". And that does help. Thanks!!